# Error: Cannot find module './definitions/init' while parsing file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I got this error when running `watchify -t babelify --presets es2015 --presets react -d -e javascripts/main.jsx -o public/bundle.js -v`.

```
Error: Cannot find module './definitions/init' while parsing file: /home/Desktop/front/javascripts/main.jsx
```

I have run `npm install`. I ran `npm install -g npm`. I ran `npm install -g definition`. But it didn't work.

I have not idea what `definitions/init` is. My `main.jsx` is as follows

```
import Wrapper from './wrapper.js';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

render(
    <Wrapper/>,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```

Any one have any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary API for rendering into the DOM looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(reactElement, domContainerNode)
```

---

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

You also need to import ReactDOM like so:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
```

Here is the official React tutorial:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html

Here are the ReactDOM docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/01/react-render-and-top-level-api.html